# Odd behavior of matrix multiplication with threading in Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am trying to do some linear algebra in `Threads.@threads for` loop, and it returns some weird results. It seems that matrices are not multiplied properly in the loop. Is it safe to do in a threaded for loop?

Below is a minimal working example to generate a `TxR` table of `NxN` matrices. For each of `R` iterations the (t+1)-th matrix is the product the (t)-th with another random matrix. The multiplications are performed by different threads, and then checked for correctness by one thread. The function should return a matrix of zeros. It does so for `N<=3`, however, there are a few ones in the result for `N>=4`.

```
function testMM(T, R, N)
    m1 = zeros(Int64, (T,R,N,N))
    m2 = rand(0:2, (T-1,R,N,N))
    m1[1,:,:,:] = rand(0:1,(R,N,N))
    Threads.@threads for i=1:R
        for t=2:T
            m1[t,i,:,:] = m2[t-1,i,:,:] * m1[t-1,i,:,:]
        end
    end

    odds = zeros(Int64,(T-1,R))
    for i=1:R
        for t=2:T
            if m1[t,i,:,:] != m2[t-1,i,:,:] * m1[t-1,i,:,:]
                odds[t-1,i] = 1
            end
        end
    end
    return odds
end
```

`Threads.nthreads()` is 4 for me. Tested on stable 64bit Julia 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.6.0 on Windows.

Edit: This example is even simpler: several copies of a matrix are squared several times independently. The result should be the same for all copies, but the function usually returns false for `N>=4`. Looks as if the data of different threads is mixed somewhere inside BLAS.

```
function testMM2(T, R, N)
m0 = rand(0:2, (N,N))
m = [deepcopy(m0) for i=1:R]
Threads.@threads for i=1:R
    for t=1:T
        m[i] = m[i]^2
    end
end
return all(x->(x==m[1]),m)
end
```

Comment: That loop is not thread safe. Multiple threads will overwrite each other.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Would you elaborate on how the threads here are allocated/partitioned and where they are not safe?

Comment: Threads are allocated before Julia is opened. `Threads.@threads for i=1:R` will partition it to as many threads as you requested. Each will save to `m1[t,i,:,:]` simultaneously and overwrite each other. Easiest is to save into separate caches by `threadid()`, or use a separate data structure. This is already super inefficient though because Julia is column-ordered: reversing the indices will make the `*` much faster. Also, the slicing here will cost a lot. Likely, you want a matrix of matrices, not a 4D array? Fix those before threading. Will post more later?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Apologies for my confusion.  Each `i` is unique within a thread, no?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas This is a MWE, so don't care about efficiency. Suppose i=1:4, and i-th thread is allocated to work with the corresponding value of i. Are you saying that while writing to m1[t,1,:,:] thread 1 will overwrite m1[t,2,:,:]? Why?

Comment: I see. I assumed you were multithreading because you were seeing bad performance. Flipping the indices and using views will likely help more than multithreading for that. just for the MWE, see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/thread-safe-array-building/3275 . I ran into a similar problem and the fix was to split the array. In your case the indices don't actually overlap (in value, they do in some sense in memory because of the skipping) but this may be a similar problem. As to why it overwrites, I am not entirely certain. That might be a question for the devs on Discourse.

Comment: Wait, is BLAS multithreaded as well? Maybe running BLAS single-threaded in the multi-threaded loop will avoid the problem and remain as efficient as it will be running in parallel because of the Julia threads. If the operation is replaced by a non-BLAS operation the problem disappears?

Comment: Can't test it myself (because my Julia is single-threaded) but putting a `BLAS.set_num_threads(1)` before the loop might have an effect.

Comment: Same behavior with `BLAS.set_num_threads(1)`. In fact, in my project i do care about performance, so need to use multi-threaded BLAS. But regardless of my project and performance, this behavior is odd.

Comment: @DanGetz As I can see, this happens for matrix multiplication, but not for addition, adding a scalar, multiplying by a scalar, or element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @xivaxy It's definitely worth getting this problem resolved. But if performance is the goal, and the program is multi-threaded at Julia level then BLAS level multi-threading will not increase speed too much. Another route to performance is to use MKL (which is faster but proprietary) and have a look at [multithreading1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-calling-intel-mkl-functions-from-multi-threaded-applications) and [multithreading2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-threaded-intel-mkl-in-multi-thread-application)

Comment: Forcing atomic calculations seems to work.  Defining `sp = Threads.SpinLock()` and wrapping the statement with `lock(sp); m[i] = m[i]^2; unlock(sp)` seems to make it work as intended.  Might be interesting to see how fine-grained SpinLocks could be made and still have all the calculations be correct.

Comment: Is this behavior caused by the `m` Array moving around in memory?  I.e., when one thread assigns its calculated value to the `m` Array, the location of `m` in memory changes (`m` Array location assigned to result Array?). So, one thread's `m` assignment pulls the rug out from the other threads?

Comment: Yes @rickhg12hs, I think it's something to do with that. But Dan_Getz is right that BLAS should be multithreaded so this should all hurt performance more than it helps due to thrashing the cache. But I don't think BLAS will

Comment: @rickhg12hs Making the second example in-place and checking is easy enough. But `m1` and `m2` in the first example stay put and so does the problem.

Comment: @DanGetz So, does that mean threads are writing to portions of `m` and `m1` where they shouldn't?  I.e., the thread's statement's assignment writes more than what's indicated on the LHS?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Note the errors are miscalculations. Hopefully, openBLAS is safe enough not to write in random indices, but it needs checking. My guess would be openBLAS has some sort of state (to coordinate between threads), and running concurrent multi-threaded operations jumbles up this state. TL;DR version: openBLAS not re-entrant when threading, so a spinlock solution would do, or doing parallelism with forked processes would work.

Comment: Can't reproduce this anymore. Maybe it has been fixed since.